# Error when creating hyperledger fabric enviroment with IBM blockchain platform VScode extension

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I've been trying to deploy a local hyperledger fabric network on my machine and I'm getting the following error:

```
[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] startFabricRuntime
[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] fix_permissions () {

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO]     docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/network ibmblockchain/vscode-
prereqs:0.0.16 chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /network

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] }

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] trap fix_permissions EXIT

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/network -v /var/run/docker.sock:
/var/run/docker.sock --network host ibmblockchain/vscode-prereqs:0.0.16 ansible-playbook 
/network/playbook.yml

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var
/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] See 'docker run --help'.

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var
/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [INFO] See 'docker run --help'.

[5/1/2020 6:29:23 PM] [ERROR] Failed to start test: Error: Failed to execute command 
"/bin/sh" with  arguments "generate.sh" return code 125
```

I've stopped and restarted the daemon but it doesn't seem to help. When I've tried creating the test-network for the hyperledger fabric samples I get this error warning:

```
LOCAL_VERSION=2.1.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are  
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.       
===============================================
```

As you can see, the DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION isn't even listed. So I'm guessing my problem has to do with the fact that the docker image isn't being reckonginzed.

Any thoughts or ideas as to what is going on, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got all the prerequisites installed before commencing. Check out this [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/prereqs.html) to install the required materials before starting the prac. There is a step of installing docker images which is what you are missing, I guess.

Hope this is helpful.